# Wacom tablet with SDL2

Tags: windows, tablet, sdl-2, pen

I would like to read pen events and touch events from a Wacom tablet, from which I need at least the position and pressure. I saw that there are touch events in SDL2, but no events are triggered in my application with the code below. I tested with a Bamboo Touch using both the pen and my fingers.

Does SDL2 not support pens? What is the easiest alternative for me to use on Windows if not?

```
    SDL_Event event;
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
        switch (event.type)
        {
        case SDL_QUIT:
            running = false;
            break;
        case SDL_FINGERUP:
            printf("finger up: \n");
            break;
        case SDL_FINGERDOWN:
            printf("finger down: \n");
            break;
        case SDL_FINGERMOTION:
            printf("finger motion: \n");
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does `SDL_GetNumTouchDevices()` return non-zero?

Comment: @genpfault It returns 0.